# Why does htaccess URL rewrite rule does not work?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a beautiful URL for my website.

I have this type of URL: `game.php?game=some-game` and I want to show it as this: `game/some-game`. I already tried writing and rewriting rules in htaccess with no success.

Firstly, I thought that the htaccess file does not work, but the custom error pages that I entered are working properly. I tried using the `QSA` flag with no result.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?game/(.*?)/?$ /game.php?game=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /game\.php\?game=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?game\.php$ /game/%1? [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 400 /Hacknet-INC/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /Hacknet-INC/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /Hacknet-INC/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /Hacknet-INC/404.php
ErrorDocument 410 /Hacknet-INC/410.php
ErrorDocument 500 /Hacknet-INC/500.php

#Serve .htc files correctly, for IE fixes
AddType text/x-component .htc

php_value upload_max_filesize 300M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `game.php>game=some-game` should be `game.php?game=some-game`?

Comment: Where? `RewriteRule ^/?game\.php$ /game/%1? [L,R=301]` In this line?

Comment: The second sentence in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going about this the wrong way I'm afraid but feat not! This is actually a common issue people face when first working with Apache's rewrite rules.

So you got a script - `game.php` - which takes the names of games as input via the query string parameter `game`, so `game.php?game=some-game`.

Now you want to make your URLs look nice by masking them in the pattern of `game/some-game`.

The problem is that you are trying to do this by redirecting the raw script URLs to the nice one and that's pretty much what anyone first doing this sort of thing does.

The key is that you want to *mask* the URL. That is to say you want to dress the raw ugly url up as something nicer.

It isn't working because instead of masking ugly with nice you are doing it the other way around - you are masking nice with ugly.

That is to say, if you type in the ugly url it redirects to the nice one but the issue with that is that no resource exists at that location so it doesn't work.

What you need to do is this - mask the ugly url with the nice one so that when you type the nice url into the address bar the server knows to go and send the request to the ugly url and serve the resulting response up under the nice url.

You then need to go and update the links in your system to use the nice url and that's that.

The rule to achieve this is simply this:

```
RewriteRule ^game/([^/]+) game.php?game=$1 [L]
```

See an example of this here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=f6863821-b64c-5873-9bd4-9f13b6e4736e

Comment: hello. thank you for the response. it still not works. should it work in xampp, local server? because that is what i am using. it gives me the error `object not found`. Why is that?

Comment: It should work on any Apache server, no matter where. Try adding `[L]` at the end of the rewrite rule. I would then also make game.php a near blank file that just has something like 'hello' in it so you can rule out other issues when testing. If you then go to /game/whatever on your server you should see the white page with 'hello' on it.

Comment: It worked after deleting the '/' symbol from the link :D